# Using Azure migration tool to grab multiple json files from web directory

Tags: jquery, python, json, azure, migration

I am trying to grab json file from a web directory and store it in Azure documentdb. I downloaded Azure migration tool and was able to add an url and transfer 1 Json file. The data is about 100 gb and would like to get all json files only. I am sure there is a way to grab all of them at once. Any recommendations is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you want to use Azure DocumentDB Migration tool to add the urls of json file to import to documentdb? If this is your case, please refer to [the offical document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-import-data/) to know the tool usage and try to do it. If not, please post your issue clearly.